# Get the first visible Row of a NSTableView

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nstableview

I want to get the top visible row (not the top row) of a NSTableView.
There seems to be no method for this.
Is this even possible?

Thank

Comment: Call `tableView.enclosingScrollView.documentVisibleRect`, calculate the top and call `tableView.rowAtPoint()`. The table view could be flipped.

Comment: This works like a charme

Answer (score 12):

You can do this using:

```
NSRect rect = [tableView visibleRect];
NSRange rows = [tableView rowsInRect:rect];
NSInteger firstVisibleRowIndex = rows.location;
```